Milvus Error When Using Collection Search: Connection Refused and Collection Not Loaded
I am using Milvus 2.4.0, and I encounter an issue when performing a collection search. The collection query works fine, but when I attempt a search, I receive the following errors:
    [2024-08-07 10:53:27,109] WARNING in decorators: [search] retry:9, cost: 3.00s, reason: <_InactiveRpcError: StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:172.16.200.46:19530: Failed to connect to remote host: Connection refused>
    [2024-08-07 10:53:30,126] ERROR in decorators: RPC error: [search], <MilvusException: (code=101, message=failed to search: collection not loaded[collection=451674119090946895])>, <Time:{'RPC start': '2024-08-07 10:53:17.306848', 'RPC error': '2024-08-07 10:53:30.126018'}>

Here is my code:
    from config.config import *
    from pymilvus import (
        connections, utility, Collection, FieldSchema, CollectionSchema, DataType)
    
    connections.connect("default", host=MILVUS_HOST, port=MILVUS_PORT)
    collection = Collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
    collection.load()
    list_collection = utility.list_collections()
    
    # Query works fine
    res_query = collection.query(
        expr="id > 1", 
        output_fields=['id'], 
        timeout=5.0
    )
    
    # Search raises error
    img = cv2.imread('image_test/test.png')
    embedding_vec = feature_extraction(img)
    search_params = {"metric_type": "COSINE", "params": {"nprobe": 10}}
    res_search = collection.search(
        data=[embedding_vec],
        anns_field="vector",
        param=search_params,
        expr="active in [1]",
        output_fields=['id'],
        limit=TOP_K)

I have verified that the collection is loaded using collection.load() and confirmed the connection to the server using connections.connect.
Why is the search failing with connection refused and collection not loaded errors, even though the query works? Are there additional steps I need to take to ensure the collection is properly loaded for a search?
Here is my environment details FYI:
Milvus Version: 2.4.0
Host: ipv4:172.16.200.46:19530


It’s possible to print the output of the code for list_collection and collection.description, and I would like to know how many rows are in this collection.
